# Not able to communicate between two modules in an Android project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My project have two modules:

- App
- Facebook-lib

Here are my `gradle` files:

## setting.gradle

```
include ':app', ':facebook-lib'
```

## Module App gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.test"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
  compile project (':facebook-lib')
```

}

## Module Facebook-lib gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
```

}

Whenver I am trying to access `Facebook-lib` class in `App` module. It works but I can't do vice versa.
I get `com.app.test`package doesn't exist or cannot find symbol class.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: So you are trying to comunicate to `App` module from `Facebook-lib` module, aren't you? In that case add the compile dependency in the Facebook-lib `build.gradle`. Anyway, I don't think that is a good practice since you are creating circle dependencies. There must be a better way to do what you are trying to

Comment: Yes, It will create a circular dependencies but still it's not compiling

Comment: You can't create a circular dependency.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438751/how-to-communicate-between-lib-module-and-main-module might help

Answer (score 0):

**You can't achieve it.**

Your `Module App` has a dependency with the `Module Facebook library`. It means that you can use the classes inside the library in your main module.

Your `Facebook library` doesn't have a dependency with your module. It means that you can't use the classes in main module.
*Also you can't create a circular dependency.*