# How to communicate between lib module and main module

Tags: android

**CONTRUCTION**

I have 2 modules:

- `app` (application)
- `box` (library module)

**PROBLEM**

I am trying to use part of `app` module from `box` module.
The problem is that `app` module have dependency on `box` module therefore I cannot point from `box` module because that would create circular dependency.

How to get to `app` module methods from `box` module ?

Or

How to inform some receiver in `app` module that there is some data to get?

**EDIT**

I ended with 3rd module `common` that held intersection of module `app` and `box`.

Comment: You might want to take some clues from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974696/starting-activity-from-android-library-project?rq=1

Answer (score 8):

You can't call a module which is depending on your library directly. That kind of dependency would defeat the purpose of a library. But you can define an interface in your Box module, which clients of this library must implement to function propeprly.

Example:
In your Box module define an interface

```
interface ThereIsSomeDataToGet(){
   void doSomething();
}
```

And in your app module, you may call

```
Box.registerCallback(new ThereIsSomeDataToGet(){...})
```

Now in the box module you have a callback to you application module, without any hard dependencies, and when the library you have some new data, you only need to call

```
ThereIsSomeDataToGet.doSomething();
```

Comment: What if activity restarted after Box.registerCallback(new ThereIsSomeDataToGet(){...}) and before ThereIsSomeDataToGet.doSomething();?

Answer (score 2):

Further elaborating on Tom's answer, here's a fully working solution:

In your **Box** module:

```
public interface Callback {
    void doSomething();
}

private static Callback callback;

public static void setCallback(Callback callback) {
    Box.callback = callback;
}
```

In your **App** module:

```
Box.setCallback(new Box.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        // Code from App module you want to run in Box module
    }
});
```

Finally, just call `doSomething()` from your **Box** module:

```
callback.doSomething();
```

Comment: What is this Box when it comes to a real code, I can get that its a module but how can I use in code, an example will be great

Comment: It’s just a random name for a module, could be doing anything. I’m referring to the question where it’s called Box.